# My family migrated from Lübeck to Guatemala

Tags: 19th-century, germany, records

My great grandfather migrated from Lübeck to Guatemala in the late 1880's. I am trying to find certified records of his family left behind in Germany.

I tried writing to the city hall but I haven't been able to get any response. Any idea where else I can look for?

Comment: Did you order specific records from the city’s archive or  wrote a more general inquiry? Do you have any birth dates and marriage dates for those who migrated? Ordering the birth and marriage records would be a first step.

Answer (score 2):

There is a local genealogy association: [Verein für Familienforschung Lübeck](https://www.familienforschung-luebeck.de) They provide an [excellent overview](https://www.familienforschung-luebeck.de/forschung/forschungshilfen/) regarding genealogical resources related to Lübeck and offer help to researchers (please read their FAQ first).